# Ore Deposit Identification

Tags: geology, mineralogy, rocks, minerals, economic-geology

What type of ore deposit does this rock best represent?

> A rock with a porphyritic texture is cross cut by a stockwork of
> quartz veins.  Bordering the veins is extensive alteration of the host
> rock. The vein contains fine-grained (~1mm) chalcopyrite and
> molybdenite.

I believe it to be a hydrothermal ore deposit as porphyry ore formation, stockwork and the Cu-Mo-Au element list indicates.

Is this a correct line of thinking and if so is it specific enough, do you think?

Comment: Is this simply a hydrothermal - porphyry - type ore deposit?

Comment: I could be wrong, but sounds a bit like a homework question because of the way you word it?  If so, you'll need to provide some thoughts at least to show what you're thinking and that you're making a reasonable effort, as Stack Exchange doesn't exist just to feed homework answers :-)

Comment: It is indeed, however, per my comment above, I am meerly seeking confirmation that it is simply a hydrothermal ore deposit @JeopardyTempest

Comment: It'd be good to put that in the question itself... and a short thought on why you go in that direction :-)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Amended I believe :-) , do let me know if there is anything else as I am very new to this site.

Comment: Looks good, hope you get a good response, and that you can find places to contribute as well! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic description of a porphyry copper-molybdenum deposit.

What happens is that there is a magmatic intrusion (the porphyry), which then solidifies. When it solidifies, it expels acidic hydrothermal fluids which carry metals in them - most often copper (represented by chalcopyrite) but also sometimes molybdenum (represented by molybdenite).

Once the fluids hit solid rocks, they react with it, and become neutralised. The carrying capacity of the fluids diminish, and they deposit the metals into the minerals you observe. The solid rocks can be pretty much anything. It can be the porphyry itself, another porphyry that happened to be around, sedimentary rocks, or whatever.